# uaccess.h header file error in function set_fs in LKM compiling process

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, c

I was trying to compile my Linux Kernel Module and in compiling process with gcc, I got this error:

```
./arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h: In function ‘set_fs’:
./arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:32:29: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘mm_segment_t {aka struct <anonymous>}’ from type ‘struct mm_segment_t *’
  current->thread.addr_limit = fs;
```

There isn't any problem with the LKM itself because I can compile it and successfully `insmode` it on another linux system.

Here's more information:

Header file used in the LKM: asm/uaccess.h | OS details: `Linux server 4.15.0-128-generic Ubuntu`

Makefile:

```
obj-m += LKM.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to make sure your arch is x86.
If you use `#include <asm/uaccess.h>` try to replace  it with `#include <linux/uaccess.h>` .